# Associative array: Dynamically adding values creates duplicate keys

Tags: php

I declare an array like this:

```
$statement_row = array(
    "Key 1" => "",
    "Key 2" => "",
    "Key 3" => "");
```

Then I read data from one table that have corresponding keys in column 0 and value in column 3 so I loop over each row in that table like this:

```
foreach($table_row as $value){
    if(!empty($value[0])){
        $statement_row[ $value[0] ] = $value[3];
    }
}
```

This gives an array with duplicate keys of key 1, key 2 and key 3, like this:

```
array("Key 1" => "","Key 2" => "","Key 3" => "","Key 1" => "Holds value","Key 2" => "Holds value","Key 3" => "Holds value");
```

Why does it behave like this? Is $value[0] not threated the same way as the defined keys?

Comment: PHP does _not_ behave like this. There must be some difference in the keys, even if they look alike. Maybe different whitespaces. Try checking with a hexeditor.

Comment: It shouldn't behave like this as far as I know, so something else must be going on. If you can make an example that actually has this behaviour (one that we can run) it might be possible to debug this, but as is it's impossible to see what's going on I guess

Comment: Yes i guess it must be a difference, however using print_r i can't see it...

Comment: Use `var_dump` to see the difference

Comment: Probably I can't make another example with this behaviour. :) I should maybe look into hexeditor.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion u_mulder. Can however still not see any difference in the keys, only in the values wich are strings of different length.

Comment: Please provide us with the output of `var_dump(array_map('base64_encode',array_keys($statement_row)));`, that way the difference in keys can de determined by us (base64 encoded they'll survive this interfaces transport).

Comment: Possibly a VARBINARY column or something similar?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Wrikken! Actually what I had done was to use $dom->saveHTML($value) instead of $value->textContent when reading data (domdocument). Maybe your suggestion had found this as well.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers.